# Formula to select highest date from array within specific constraints

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for a formula to return one of six possible results based on which date (if any) is the highest out of all dates available that fall within a specific date range.

Consider the following layout:
Cell A1 has a fixed date (this is my lower constraint)
Cell A2 has a fixed date (this is my upper constraint)
Cells G5:K5 may contain dates or they may be blank.

If G5 and H5 both contain dates and both of those dates are between my dates in A1 and A2, then I want the result of my formula to identify which of those two is the most recent (it can show the date itself, the column header, a text string, doesn't matter as long as it is something different for each column)

If any of G5:K5 also contain other dates that fall outside of the window defined by A1 & A2 then those dates should be ignored.

If none of the dates are within the permitted range or all of the cells are blank then it can return a string like "not applicable" or an error that I can rewrite using IFERROR.

My dataset is pretty big (I'll be copying this formula down several hundred rows) so I would prefer to avoid using an {array} formula if possible - too slow. I've been staring at this worksheet long enough for my brain to have turned to mush, so if there is a straightforward approach to reaching my goal it is currently eluding me.

Any assistance greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm a little confused about the question's focus on columns G and H. Do they have special significance relative to columns I, J, and K? If I understand correctly, you want the minimum date between those in G and H, provided that both contain dates and both are between the two dates in A1 and A2. Is that correct?

Comment: @nickflees G and H are not significant, the dates could just as easily be in H & J, or I & K, etc. or maybe even have dates in 3 or 4 of the columns (though this is much less likely). In terms of which date to select, I actually want the maximum, but your other conditions are correct - the dates must be within the parameters specified in A1 & A2.

Comment: So you're looking for the maximum date in columns G through K between two fixed dates?

Comment: @nickflees precisely :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out in the end. It's not pretty, but it works.

This part returns the highest valid date:

MAX(IF(AND(G5>=$A$1,G5<=$A$2),G5,0),IF(AND(H5>=$A$1,H5<=$A$2),H5,0),IF(AND(I5>=$A$1,I5<=$A$2),I5,0),IF(AND(J5>=$A$1,J5<=$A$2),J5,0),IF(AND(K5>=$A$1,K5<=$A$2),K5,0))

And then by nesting it I can convert the results to a different text string depending on which column contains the "winner".

=IF(AND(MAX(IF(AND(G5>=$A$1,G5<=$A$2),G5,0),IF(AND(H5>=$A$1,H5<=$A$2),H5,0),IF(AND(I5>=$A$1,I5<=$A$2),I5,0),IF(AND(J5>=$A$1,J5<=$A$2),J5,0),IF(AND(K5>=$A$1,K5<=$A$2),K5,0))=G5,G5<>""),"CA",IF(AND(MAX(IF(AND(G5>=$A$1,G5<=$A$2),G5,0),IF(AND(H5>=$A$1,H5<=$A$2),H5,0),IF(AND(I5>=$A$1,I5<=$A$2),I5,0),IF(AND(J5>=$A$1,J5<=$A$2),J5,0),IF(AND(K5>=$A$1,K5<=$A$2),K5,0))=H5,H5<>""),"MX",IF(AND(MAX(IF(AND(G5>=$A$1,G5<=$A$2),G5,0),IF(AND(H5>=$A$1,H5<=$A$2),H5,0),IF(AND(I5>=$A$1,I5<=$A$2),I5,0),IF(AND(J5>=$A$1,J5<=$A$2),J5,0),IF(AND(K5>=$A$1,K5<=$A$2),K5,0))=I5,I5<>""),"BR",IF(AND(MAX(IF(AND(G5>=$A$1,G5<=$A$2),G5,0),IF(AND(H5>=$A$1,H5<=$A$2),H5,0),IF(AND(I5>=$A$1,I5<=$A$2),I5,0),IF(AND(J5>=$A$1,J5<=$A$2),J5,0),IF(AND(K5>=$A$1,K5<=$A$2),K5,0))=J5,J5<>""),"IQS",IF(AND(MAX(IF(AND(G5>=$A$1,G5<=$A$2),G5,0),IF(AND(H5>=$A$1,H5<=$A$2),H5,0),IF(AND(I5>=$A$1,I5<=$A$2),I5,0),IF(AND(J5>=$A$1,J5<=$A$2),J5,0),IF(AND(K5>=$A$1,K5<=$A$2),K5,0))=K5,K5<>""),"Other","Not Applicable")))))

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand now. The following formula will get you the maximum date in the range G5:K5, subject to the condition that it be between the dates in A1 and A2. It will return "not applicable in the event that none of the dates meet the condition.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(G5:K5,">="&$A$1,G5:K5,"<="&$A$2)<5,LARGE(G5:K5,1+COUNTIFS(G5:K5,">"&$A$2)),"not applicable")
```

Comment: This approach works as long as G and H (and any other columns included) all have dates in them, but sometimes the cells in those columns will be blank. The AND portion would get a FALSE value under those circumstances.

Comment: Added conditions for neither cell being blank.

Comment: This will work for two columns, but if I expand it to the full five columns it is going to require all five columns to have values in them before it will move to "value if true" part of the formula.

Comment: I'm reworking. I think I understand what you mean now. You're basically looking for a MAX-IF kind of construction without using an array formula, right? I'm working on it now.